# Updating package (buefy) breaks project (filegator) - import issues(?)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

I am trying to add some features to [filegator](https://github.com/filegator/filegator), a self hosted file storage. 
(The project is organized as single-file components, if that is of any relevance.) 
(It is based on Vue,js and runs as a Node.js server, with babel)
For this, I want to update the used [buefy](https://github.com/buefy/buefy) version, to utilize some newer features. 
One of the intermediate version was [code breaking](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/releases/tag/v0.8.0), the suggested solution was however already implemented:

If you [check here](https://github.com/buefy/buefy#2-import-and-use-buefy), it suggests to

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Buefy from 'buefy';
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';

Vue.use(Buefy);
```

It already did this, while using a version that was before the breaking changes, in filegators [main.js](https://github.com/filegator/filegator/blob/master/frontend/main.js), lines 1, 5 and 25.
However, I still get the following error message:
[image]
I already tried to import buefy the same way in the [Browser.vue](https://github.com/filegator/filegator/blob/master/frontend/views/Browser.vue), which contains the b-table that throws the error, but it didnt help. (Was I on the right track, do I need to import packages in each component seperately?)

What confuses me even more is that the article informing about the [breaking changes](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/releases/tag/v0.8.0) suggests to

```
import { Table } from 'buefy'
```

while the [official documentations code](https://buefy.org/documentation/table) uses

```
b-table
```

However, I can not import individual components with hyphens in their name. That throws its own errors.
I feel this should probably be pretty easy and I am overlooking something obvious.
Could someone please point me in the right direction?
 Thank you! :)

Comment: What is the version of Buefy you are using (both current and target)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is import issue as that would probably lead to an app not building at all. But your error message is from the browser where app is already loaded and executing.

1. The breaking change in v0.8.0 is only for imports of individual components. What [the docs](https://github.com/buefy/buefy#2-import-and-use-buefy) say is that you can import and install all Buefy components at once (`Vue.use(Buefy);` ....usually in `main.js`) or just install and use only selected components. As `filegator` is using the 1st option, this is not a change causing your problems...
2. By the looks of the error and stack trace, it seems the problem is rather in the breaking change in version [v0.9.0](https://github.com/buefy/buefy/releases/tag/v0.9.0) where the `BTable` component default slot and table column syntax changed

Old syntax:

```html
<b-table :data="myData">
    <template slot-scope="props">
        <b-table-column field="name" label="Name">
            {{ props.row.name }}
        </b-table-column>
        <b-table-column field="age" numeric label="Age">
            {{ props.row.age }}
        </b-table-column>
    </template>
</b-table>
```

New syntax:

```html
<b-table :data="myData">
    <b-table-column field="name" label="Name" v-slot="props">
        {{ props.row.name }}
    </b-table-column>
    <b-table-column field="age" label="Age">
        <template v-slot:default="props">
            {{ props.row.age }}
        </template>
    </b-table-column>
</b-table>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you a million times for taking your time to answer! I feel dumb, but happy! It works now! I wish you all the best!